# combine boolean varible of all objects in an arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of self defined objects (e.g., person). each obj has a boolean variable v1 (e.g., isMale). I want to check if v1 of all objs in this arraylist is true on v1, if so, return true, if any obj has v1 == false, return false. I can write a loop to achieve this. But I am wondering if there is faster way to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use **Stream API's terminal function *anyMatch*** to improve performance

```
List<YourClass> list = Arrays.asList(// list of objects)
boolean result = list.stream().anyMatch((obj) -> !obj.isMale);  // your required value
```

Comment: Or `allMatch`; also, `anyMatch(not(Person::isMale))` with `Predicate.not`.

Comment: thx. is it different for list vs arraylist? I used arraylist because I want flexible length

Comment: @sophiadw, Yes if you want to fixed length list then use Arrays.asList  or else you can use new ArrayList to get dynamic list.

The asList() method of java.util.Arrays class is used to return a fixed-size list backed by the specified array (i.e. both array and list will have same reference).

While,
new ArrayList will create full independent copy of array.